Where can I find the Shivat Tzion Tiklal
I am trying to find a Yemenite Shivat Tzion Tiklal to buy, but there are a very limited number of results on Google. Can anyone help me find it?
I want to find a source to the oldest, least changed or updated version of prayer, in a Yemenite rite. If you think that the Yemenite Shivat Tzion Tiklal is not the siddur I should search for, can you give me tips on what to look for?
Thank you.

Welcome to MiYodeya Nerina and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

I believe the תכלאל-בלדי siddur is the accepted one. At least according to my friend. Are you looking to buy a physical copy?

Here is an app on google play store, if that helps to use in the interim.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.issahar.tiklal

Are you looking in Israel, USA, Europe?

Within Yemen there were different regionally based nushaoth in circulation, the two main distinctions being between Baladi and Shami. You seem to be more interested in the Baladi. R. Qafih's tiklal Shibhath Sion within the Baladi nusah was intended to be somewhat accomodationist to appeal to a broad base of Baladi users, and defers slightly more to the Maharitz than the Rambam. His later Siah Yerushalayim leans slightly more towards the Rambam in its representation of the Baladi nusah - this being in line the tradition of the Dardai community from which he came.

It can be debated which is more representative of "the oldest, least changed or updated version of prayer, in a Yemenite rite" - IMHO I believe R. Qafih would say that the tiklal Siah Yerushalayim is a better representation (and it is also more readily available).

@Shababnik thank you very much for the tips. I am looking to buy a physical copy in Europe.

@Deuteronomy thank you very much for the explanation. I wasn't born Jewish, so I don't have links to a tradition from my family. I have the Artscroll complete Siddur in the Ashkenaz tradition, because I live in Europe I thought I should start there. But there are things added to prayer, because of something European Jews have experienced, and I just can not relate to that. I tried, but I feel like a fake.

@Deuteronomy Simultaneously I was getting interested in the Yemenite tradition because I am learning Hebrew pronunciation as unchanged as possible. I discovered that finding the least changed way of reading, praying, etc. feels significant to me personally, and I can deeply relate to that way of doing things. Not that I think that other ways are wrong, who am I to think that. I will also look for the tiklal Siah Yerushalayim.

@mbloch Thank you!

@NerinaCorbadzic It is always helpful in one's development to attach ones self to a living, breathing, community. Even if that means following along with what is to you a non-preferred nusah in the interim. Sadly I think you'll find it difficult to find a Yemenite minyan in Europe. Nevertheless, here's to wishing you tremendous success on your journey! The title in Hebrew (in case you had difficulty with my transliteration) is שיח ירושלים and it comes as a 6 volume set. It can be ordered from https://net-sah.org/ (you will probably have to correspond with them about shipping to Europe).

@NerinaCorbadzic "because of something European Jews have experienced" Part of becoming Jewish is becoming part of the community. Rambam writes as much in his letter to Ovadia the Ger https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/247248 If you have converted to Judaism, then Avraham is your father too (and you can say so in prayers אלהי אבותינו אלהי אברהם אלהי יצחק...) and those Jews in Europe are your relatives too. Things that happened to them are relevant to you too.

@DoubleAA I understand what you are saying, I should accept it as my history, but I feel like I'm pretending. As I don't have current family ties with any tradition, I feel like I'm faking it, and that's not a good feeling, because I want to be honest when I'm praying. I'm still learning, so I think going to the oldest version that we have, will be good for me. When I have ties to any specific tradition, recognizing and understanding the additions will be easier.

This answer includes material I wrote in the comments above:
The תכלאל שיבת ציון was published in 1952 and has been out of print for more than half a century. If one wanted to procure this three volume set their best bet would probably be at a second-hand/used seforim store in Israel. It is possible to come across it intermittently through used online book-sellers but unless you happen to come across the listing at the right time/place, chances are fairly slim that you will be able to find it.
Within Yemen there were different regionally based nushaoth in circulation, the two main distinctions being between Baladi and Shami. Based on your request, you seem to be more interested in the nusah Baladi. R. Qafih's tiklal Shibhath Sion (תכלאל שיבת ציון) within the Baladi nusah was intended to be somewhat accomodationist in order to appeal to a broad base of Baladi users, and defers slightly more to the Maharitz than the Rambam. His later Siah Yerushalayim (שיח ירושלים) leans slightly more towards the Rambam in its representation of the Baladi nusah - this being in line the tradition of the Dardai community from which he came.
It can be debated which is more representative of "the oldest, least changed or updated version of prayer, in a Yemenite rite." R. Qafih (who put together both versions) would say that the Siah Yerushalayim is a more faithful representation of the earliest versions of the Yemenite (Baladi) nusah. He was of the view that the Rambam directly drew his siddur from the Yemenites, therefore in composing Siah Yerushalayim in a manner that draws back on the Rambam he sought to re-align nusah Baladi with its earliest strains.
The Siah Yerushalayim is a six volume set and is more readily available, with various online peddlers carrying it. The most direct would be through  net-sah.org. You will probably have to correspond with them to arrange for shipping to Europe (if I recall correctly Vered is the person you will want to speak with, she is very helpful).
